# onSetItemClickListener not working

Tags: android, list, listview

Hey I saw many solutions but none pertain to me... I am using an actionBarActivity with a toolbar and cannot get the `mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {`

This is the code:

```
     mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        addDrawerItems();
        setupDrawer();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

public void addDrawerItems() {
Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "ADDING DRAWER ITEMS");
        drawerAdapter = new DrawerAdapter(this);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(drawerAdapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "DRAWER ITEMS CLICKED");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Time for an upgrade!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(position == 2) {
                    takeUserToProfile();
                }
            }
        });


}


public class DrawerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> drawerItems;

    public DrawerAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        drawerItems = setupItems();

    }

    private ArrayList<String> setupItems() {
        ArrayList<String> drawerItemNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        drawerItemNames.add("Search");
        drawerItemNames.add("Home");
        drawerItemNames.add("Profile");
        drawerItemNames.add("Share");
        drawerItemNames.add("Logout");

        return drawerItemNames;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_item, null);
        }

        TextView drawerItem = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.drawerItem);
        drawerItem.setText(drawerItems.get(position));

        return v;
    }

}
```

This is the xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The first child in the layout is for the main Activity UI-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="#ffffffff">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Holy Operating Systems, Batdroid!"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">
        <TextView android:text="U titel"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Theme"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <!-- Side navigation drawer UI -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navList"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>


    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:id="@+id/mainParentLayout"
        android:gravity="center">

        <com.alamkanak.weekview.WeekView
            android:id="@+id/weekView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:eventTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:textSize="12sp"
            app:hourHeight="60dp"
            app:headerColumnPadding="8dp"
            app:headerColumnTextColor="#8f000000"
            app:headerRowPadding="12dp"
            app:columnGap="8dp"
            app:noOfVisibleDays="3"
            app:headerRowBackgroundColor="#ffefefef"
            app:dayBackgroundColor="#05000000"
            app:todayBackgroundColor="#1848adff"
            app:headerColumnBackground="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_above="@+id/updateButtonLayout"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/updateButtonLayout"></LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

this is the adapter list item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:id="@+id/drawerItem"
        />

    <View android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:background="#222222"
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical ="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/drawerItem"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In all devices it is not working or any specific version device? Set `android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` for your custom layout `UI` elements and set `android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` for listview.

Comment: Tried that too, it is not working still

Comment: @Lion789 please post your entire activity code.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this in **Adapter** class like this

```
 drawerItem.setOnClickListner(new OnClickListner(){

       public void onClick(View v) {
         Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "DRAWER ITEMS CLICKED");
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Time for an upgrade!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 Integer position = (Integer) v.getTag();
                if(position == 2) {
                    takeUserToProfile();
                }
}
});
```

Comment: I originally tried to do that it did not work as well

Comment: There is no error it just does not get clicked...nothing is shown

Comment: you have implement this code. this is working for me

Comment: it is the xml since there are more than two child views for the drawer layout... do you know how I am suppose to combine the first toolbar and listview together... I tried just wrapping it in a relative layout but then the list view does not get hidden

Comment: do you want to implement navigation drawer in Material design

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the List will  not be able to make the Click Listener to pass. add this attribute to the top most layout of your XML where you have provided the ListView elements.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

or try this

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: It will work i am also using same thing in my application.. put some logs and check those logs. show those logs for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Add only the layout_gravity = "start" for your drawer list. Remove the "left|" in the navDrawerList. it will work as I have run your code.

<strike>android:layout_gravity="left|start"</strike>
**android:layout_gravity="start"**